# Can I change an an existing virtualenv to ignore global site packages? (like --no-site-package on a new one)

Tags: python, virtualenv

I can create a new virtualenv that ignores global site-packages with "--no-site-package". Is it possible to change an existing virtualenv (which was created without "--no-site-package") to also ignore the global site-packages? (So that it workes like it was created with "--no-site-package" in the first place.)

thanks in advance,

Sebastian

Answer (score 20):

I think all you have to do is create an empty file called `no-global-site-packages.txt` and put it into the virtualenv's python2.x folder (eg, `lib/python2.6/`, the one with all the modules). Then the normal site.py generated by virtualenv detects the difference and handles everything from there.

Comment: Thank you, that pointed me in the right direction. The file has to be in the lib/pythonX.Y/ directory (inside the virtualenv-directory), not in site-packages, though.

Answer (score 9):

Can you just create a new one and then re-create it with the `--no-site-package`?  If you use [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/) then you can use `pip freeze > requirements.pip` to generate a requirements file to re-install into your new virtualenv.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this suggestion; have wasted hours because stupid Conda messed up my system. Thanks! :)