# python and bpython using different PYTHONPATHs in Virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv, pythonpath

Something strange and unexpected is happening with the sys.path of any virtual environment I set. For example, a clean env:

```
$ virtualenv test
$ source test/bin/activate
(test) $
```

This is the expected PYTHONPATH:

```
(test) $ python
>>> import sys
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/home/user/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
/home/user/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg
/home/user/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
/home/user/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg
/home/user/test/lib/python2.7
/home/user/test/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/home/user/test/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/user/test/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/home/user/test/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/user/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/home/user/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But this is the one I really get:

```
(test) $ bpython
>>> import sys
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/usr/bin
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

I can't figure out the reason of the two different sys.paths.
Because of that, no pip installation works!
I'm using Virtualenv 1.7.2, Ubuntu 12.04, Python 2.7.3.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**My hypothesis is that you have not installed bpython after you have activated the new virtualenv.**

I followed it up exactly like you mentioned:

```
mkvirtualenv bpython
(bpython)~ $ pip install bpython
(bpython)~ $bpython
```

and then ran the commands:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/bin
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python27.zip
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

and did the same thing again by running python under the activated virtualenv

```
(bpython)~ $ python
.....
>>> import sys
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python27.zip
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/bpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

**I saw no difference in the two results**

Comment: You're right. I thought that virtualenv would change PYTHONPATH for any other program since it is active. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than installing one copy of bpython per virtualenv, I've added this function to my shell profile (for example `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`). It wraps the bpython command with some logic to load the virtual environment's python path (if you have an active virtual environment).

```
bpython() {
    if test -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV"
    then
        PYTHONPATH="$(python -c 'import sys; print ":".join(sys.path)')" \
        command bpython "$@"
    else
        command bpython "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: +1. This solution worked for me when the `--no-site-packages` solution didn't.

Comment: I don't like this method, but I really think it is the best option.

Answer (score 8):

I found that I needed to deactivate and reactivate my virtualenv after installing bpython for it to work.

1. `pip install bpython`
2. `deactivate`
3. `. bin/activate` # or your equivalent activation command

Answer (score 2):

I also discovered that if you have bpython installed locally, you need to create your virtualenv with `--no-site-packages` for it to work properly. If you created your virtualenv without that flag, you can create an empty file named `no-global-site-packages.txt` in `~/.virtualenvs/<env-name>/lib/python2.7/` as noted in [this Stack Exchange answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873294/can-i-change-an-an-existing-virtualenv-to-ignore-global-site-packages-like-n).