# Is it possible to set --no-site-packages in virtualenv after it's already set up?

Tags: python, virtualenv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change an an existing virtualenv to ignore global site packages? (like --no-site-package on a new one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873294/can-i-change-an-an-existing-virtualenv-to-ignore-global-site-packages-like-n)

I have a virtualenv set up, with plenty of packages installed that I don't want to reinstall.  Is there a way to set up this existing virtualenv so that it does not use the global site-packages directory?

FYI, this is primarily motivated by getting this warning:
`UserWarning: Module X was already imported from`
every time I start up, e.g., mercurial.

Related, but doing the inverse: [Revert the `--no-site-packages` option with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371136/revert-the-no-site-packages-option-with-virtualenv).  This implies that all I need is a `lib/no-global-site-packages.txt` file, but an empty one of those seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See also for the inverse: [Modifying a virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433198/modifying-a-virtualenv).

For completeness I'll post the inverse instructions of my answer there. Eventually this question can be merged with the other one.

Since `--no-site-packages` is the default behaviour on recent versions ([>= 1.7](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/news.html#id8)) of *virtualenv*, you just need to recreate the *virtualenv* with the command:

```
$ virtualenv $PATH_TO_VIRTUALENV
```

or on older versions where `--system-site-packages` was the default behaviour:

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages $PATH_TO_VIRTUALENV
```

replacing `$PATH_TO_VIRTUALENV` with the path to the existing *virtualenv*. This will reinstall the *virtualenv*, reconfiguring it to prevent access to global packages, while keeping the packages already installed there.

Comment: Tried this, but with python2.7 it tells me that I'm asking the wrong question... `The --no-site-packages flag is deprecated; it is now the default behavior.`  And I'm still getting the UserWarning's.  I'll probably accept this answer, since it's technically the right answer to mine in the title, but something is still awry.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Revised the answer to the most correct one taking into account the default behaviour on recent versions.